# How can I grab the date of the last post on my blogger blog and display it on another site?

Tags: javascript, blogger

I want to put a link to my blog on my website, and I wan the link to look something like this:

Blog - *last post: Title - 9-June-2013*

How can I grab the title and date of my last post?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following Alfonso's suggestion, this is the code I've gone for. Where #blogdate is a span element.

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
google.load("feeds", "1");
function feedLoaded(result) {
    if (!result.error) {
          var pubDate = result.feed.entries[0].publishedDate;
          var date = new Date(pubDate);
          var months = Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");
          var pubDateString = date.getDate() + " " + months[date.getMonth()] + " " + date.getFullYear()
          $('#blogdate').text("last post: '" + result.feed.entries[0].title + "' on " + pubDateString); 
    }
}
function OnLoad() {
   var feed = new google.feeds.Feed(**XML URL**);
   feed.load(feedLoaded);
}
google.setOnLoadCallback(OnLoad);
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

It is likely that your blog supports RSS. RSS provides an xml file with your recent updates so you could for example use a javascript / jQuery based parser to parse this file and get your last post date, title and link.

Comment: Good suggestion, thanks. It's a blogger blog so the main feed is Atom. Know of a quick bit of code?

Comment: Access control same origin issues are stopping this be simple. I've tried this jquery, but it won't work for my domain directly to the XML code.. Any tips? http://www.hardcode.nl/archives_139/article_586-parse-rss-xml-with-jquery.htm

Comment: Sorry, I did not see this until now.